# Finding confidence intervals

Tags: r, probability, standard-error

I am doing some homework and this is the question:

*Create the data frame june_polls containing only Brexit polls ending in June 2016 (enddate of "2016-06-01" and later). We will calculate confidence intervals for all polls and determine how many cover the true value of  d .*

First, I use `dplyr::mutate` to calculate a plug-in estimate se_x_hat for the standard error of the estimate  SE^[X]  for each poll given its sample size and value of  X^  (x_hat). Second, use `dplyr::mutate` again to calculate an estimate for the standard error of the spread for each poll given the value of se_x_hat. Then, use `dplyr::mutate` a third time, to calculate upper and lower bounds for 95% confidence intervals of the spread. Last, add a column hit that indicates whether the confidence interval for each poll covers the correct spread  d=−0.038 .

Below is the code I have tried already.

```
library(dslabs)
library(dplyr)
data(brexit_polls)

brexit_polls <- brexit_polls %>%
  mutate(x_hat = (spread + 1)/2)

p <- 0.481

june_polls <- brexit_polls %>% filter(enddate >= as.Date("2016-06-01")) %>%
  mutate(se_x_hat = sqrt((x_hat*(1-x_hat))/samplesize)) %>% 
  mutate(se_spread = 2*se_x_hat) %>% 
  mutate(lower_spread = x_hat - qnorm(0.975)*se_spread) %>%
  mutate(upper_spread = x_hat + qnorm(0.975)*se_spread) 

mutate(june_polls, hit = between(0.495, lower_spread, upper_spread))
```

This is the error that I receive: `Error: Expecting a single value: [extent=32]`.

I also think I might be calculating something wrong in the code, because all of my values for the upper and lower confidence intervals are positive when they shouldn't be.

Comment: Why your values for upper and lower confidence intervals should not be positive? (I know we go a bit away of programming question)

Comment: To come back to programming, I do not know what you are trying to do in the last line, but if you look at the documentation `between`takes a vector as first argument and two constant values. What you try to achieve can be done with `mutate(june_polls, hit = (lower_spread<0.495 & upper_spread>0.495))`

Answer (score 0):

I am not a 100% sure what you are trying to do, or what you mean with 'covers the correct spread d=−0.038', but if you simply want to see if p is contained in the 95% confidence interval of your Bernoulli distribution, you can use:

```r
june_polls <- brexit_polls %>% filter(enddate >= as.Date("2016-06-01")) %>%
  mutate(se_x_hat = sqrt((x_hat*(1-x_hat))/samplesize)) %>% 
  mutate(se_spread = 2*se_x_hat) %>% 
  mutate(lower_spread = x_hat - qnorm(0.975)*se_spread) %>%
  mutate(upper_spread = x_hat + qnorm(0.975)*se_spread) %>%
  mutate(hit = ifelse(p > lower_spread & p < upper_spread, TRUE, FALSE))
```